# Deferring Incrementation of A Counter Every 24 Hours

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made an animation similar to the periscope hearts feature. 
[My Implementation](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nzxwkwnuabqdpvb/BB792CF5-6FF7-4701-8AFA-956F576C069A-78418-000380567E8B1776.gif?dl=0)

Right now it the counter keeps incrementing every time you press on the button. My objective is to stop the counter from counting every 24 hours but keep the part where a user can click on the button to activate the heart animation.

```
$('#heartActivate').click(function() {

        // Calculate 24 hours in milliseconds
        var second = 1000;
        var minute = 60 * second;
        var hour = 60 * minute;
        var day = 24 * hour;

        var now = Date.now();
        var tomorrow = now + day;

        localStorage.setItem('next-active-time', tomorrow);

        var nextActiveTime = localStorage.getItem('next-active-time') || 0;
        if (Date.now() < nextActiveTime) {

          var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
          var flows = ["flowOne", "flowTwo", "flowThree"];
          var colors = ["colOne", "colTwo", "colThree", "colFour", "colFive", "colSix"];
          var timing = (Math.random() * (4.3 - 0.3) + 1.6).toFixed(1);
          // Animate Particle
          $('<div class="particle part-' + rand + ' ' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + '" style="font-size:' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (37 - 22) + 22) + 'px;"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div>').appendTo('.particle-box').css({ animation: "" + flows[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + " " + timing + "s linear" });
          $('<div class="particle part-' + rand + ' ' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + '" style="font-size:' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (37 - 22) + 22) + 'px;"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div>').appendTo('.particle-box').css({ animation: "" + flows[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + " " + timing + "s linear" });
          $('.part-' + rand).show();
          // Remove Particle
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('.part-' + rand).remove();
          }, timing * 1000 - 100);  
          $('#output').html(function(i, val) {
            return parseInt(val, 10) + 1;
          });
          return false;
        }
```

[JSFiddle of all my code](https://jsfiddle.net/cramlabs/mcto9ecL/6/)

**Objective: Keep the heart animation when button clicked but only increment the counter on button click every 24 hours**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work on jsfiddle, however the setLocalStorage is blocked here (https://jsfiddle.net/mcto9ecL/16/) you will see the counter go from 1 to 2, then stop increment after the localStorage token is set to tomorrow

your main issue is that you are always setting the localStorage to tomorrow, which means today will never be the day to update the counter.

you needed to check if the local storage exists, and use it, otherwise create it.

**(however a user could remove the storage from there browser and keep pressing the button)**

your logic of comparing the date was flawed (reversed) today (date.now()) is always less than tomorrow since you are generating it each time)

I separated the code out to make the main logic within the click function more clear and added some comments to explain it

```js
function showAnimation() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  var flows = ["flowOne", "flowTwo", "flowThree"];
  var colors = ["colOne", "colTwo", "colThree", "colFour", "colFive", "colSix"];
  var timing = (Math.random() * (4.3 - 0.3) + 1.6).toFixed(1);
  // Animate Particle
  $('<div class="particle part-' + rand + ' ' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + '" style="font-size:' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 22) + 22) + 'px;"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div>').appendTo('.particle-box').css({
    animation: "" + flows[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + " " + timing + "s linear"
  });
  $('<div class="particle part-' + rand + ' ' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + '" style="font-size:' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 22) + 22) + 'px;"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div>').appendTo('.particle-box').css({
    animation: "" + flows[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + " " + timing + "s linear"
  });
  $('.part-' + rand).show();
  // Remove Particle
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.part-' + rand).remove();
  }, timing * 1000 - 100);
  return false;
}

function incrementCounter() {
  $('#output').html(function(i, val) {
    console.log(i, val);
    return parseInt(val, 10) + 1;
  });
}

function getTomorrow(today) {
  // Calculate 24 hours in milliseconds
  var second = 1000;
  var minute = 60 * second;
  var hour = 60 * minute;
  var day = 24 * hour;

  return today + day;
}
$('#heartActivate').click(function() {

  var today = Date.now();
  var tomorrow = getTomorrow(today);

  showAnimation(); //show hearts

  //calculate if we need to increase counter or return false
  //check if they already have a next-active-time stored on the browser
  var nextActiveTime = localStorage.getItem('next-active-time') || 0; 
  if (!nextActiveTime) {
    //they havent clicked before increment and set tommorows time in local storage
    localStorage.setItem('next-active-time', tomorrow);
    incrementCounter();
    return true
  }

  if (today >= nextActiveTime) { 
 // if today is greater than or equal to nextActiveTime increment by 1
    incrementCounter();
    localStorage.setItem('next-active-time', tomorrow);
    return true
  }
  //else do nothing we are not past tommorow yet

  return false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="heartActivate" type="button">Activate Heart</button>
<div class="particle-box"></div>
<div id="output">1</div>
```

Comment: While this code might work the answer itself  isn't very valuable in the long term without an explanation of what was changed. It basically relies on people to have to be diff tools and scan for differences

Comment: Well that again means scanning for differences. Not hard to write up a brief explanation and is the proper thing to do ... why wasn't it working and what was done to resolve it

Comment: sorry I will write something up now

Comment: don't apologize or take it as an attack... just trying to help promote quality as well as OP learns more from overview

Comment: if you are using chrome press F12 navigate to resources and delete your local storage for jsfiddle sandbox fiddle.jshell.net, next-active-time token (this will be stopping it increment because it is not yet tommorow (would still be stored from your previous code) , if you delete the storage you will see you can press it once, it will go to 2, then not increment after the storage is set

Comment: @user2950720 In the jsfiddle it should start at 0 when you click the button for the first time it should increment by 1 every time after that it should only activate the heart animation if 24 hours have passed then you will be able to increment the counter again

Comment: sorry above you stated "but keep the part where a user can click on the button to activate the heart animation." I assumed you wanted the animation with no increment. you can also change it to start at 0, thats set by your html <div id="output">1</div> to <div id="output">0</div>

Comment: move the showAnimation() call into the if (today >= nextActiveTime) {  area if you only want the animation on increment

Comment: @user2950720 correct, i want to keep the part where the user can activate the heart animation without increment but I don't see it ever incrementing

Comment: @user2950720 Thank you so much. You don't know how much this helped me